# Set focus to the subject field in "new message" form using C# Add-In for Outlook 2007

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

I just need to know how to set focus for the subject field of the "new message" form once it is opened.. Can this be achieved ?!

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: The interaction object would be still the `mailItem`.
But I guess there is no `FocusSubject()` method or equal.
The [docu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem_members.aspx) doesn't provide any method and I didn't find any due to my latest developments.

Comment: I've already checked the `mailItem` and didn't found anything useful.. Thank you anyway for your help @Herdo. I really appreciate it.

Comment: So what's your purpose with setting the focus to the subject?

Comment: I was asked to do it in order to make things a little bit easier for the users to fill in the subject.. It's the final touch in something larger I've already done. That's it.

Comment: You may take a look [here](http://www.windows-tech.info/16/044fa05f79b861a3.php).

Comment: Alright.. I'm checking it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

- The Outlook API exposes methods for retrieving the current inspector, explorer or either or. I believe you'll get back a number (HWND) which is a window handle.
- You can then use the Win32 API to find that window, and then find a child window
- Use Spy++ from Visual Studio Tools menu, and you will find the subject field doesn't have a unique caption. You'll have to find the label which has a caption of "S&ubject", and the next Window in the list should be the RichEdit20WPT subject textbox.
- Finally, use the appropriate Win32 function to focus the field.

You'll need to `[DllImport]` the `user32.dll`

I leave it up to you to implement, and if you need help there are plenty of examples out there on how do use the win32 api to perform the tasks outlined above.

Answer (score 0):

declare:

```
private Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms.Control txtToCtrl;
```

initiailize:

```
this.txtToCtrl = (Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms.Control)GetFormRegionControl("_RecipientControl1");
```

when ready:

```
this.txtToCtrl.SetFocus();
```

Comment: would you mind expanding a bit upon your answer? What does one achieve adding those snippets?